# what's the name for an HTML SELECT control's visible portion?

Tags: html, xhtml

I've looked far and wide, but could not find anything.

Is there an "anatomy of HTML elements" guide of sorts that has this kind of information?

**EDIT:** By "visible" I mean "visible by default", without user (or anything else for that matter) having engaged it.

Comment: Why do you need to know? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You want to know how to get the selected element of a `<select>`?

Comment: I just need a name to be able to refer to this thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"the dropdown (arrow|icon|button)" is the name of the thing on the right side and "selected value display" is the (usually) white box with the default/selected value. As far as I know, there are no standard names for the [shadow dom](http://glazkov.com/2011/01/14/what-the-heck-is-shadow-dom/)

Answer (score 1):

I would call this "selected value". In ASP.Net, for example, that's the property name for the visible value in a drop down list control (a SELECT input).

Answer (score 1):

If, by visible portion, you mean 'What option is visible by default (or on the initial load)", what you need to do is add 'selected="selected"' to the option tag you want to show eg:

```
<select name="tester">
    <option value="1">First Option</option>
    <option value="2">Second Option</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">Third Option</option>
    <option value="4">Fourth Option</option>
</select>
```

This would display a select box with 'Third Option' showing in it.

You can find out more about `<select>` and `<option>` on W3 Schools:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the CSS display property? Also might help to understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Nope, I'm referring to the portion you see before you click on it and to reveal all the available options.